# Automate renaming of video files

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, file-rename

I have a lot of files I want to rename and it would take me a long time to do them manually. They are video files and are usually in this format - "NAME OF SHOW - EPISODE NUMBER - EPISODE NAME", so for example "Breaking Bad - 101 - Pilot".

What I would like to do is change the "101" part to my own convention of "S01E01". I figure that in one series of a show the only sequential part of that string is the last number, ie. S01E01, S01E02, S01E03, S01E04 etc...

Would anyone be able to give me advice on how to do this on terminal on Mac OS X. I believe it is too complicated to do with Automator or other batch renaming programs...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for FOO in *; do mv "$FOO" "`echo $FOO | sed 's/\([^-]*\) - \([0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\(.*\)/\1 - S0\2E\3\4/g'`" ; done
```

This works if there are less than 10 seasons.

Comment: That's great.. How would I target the files that are required with this?

Comment: Run it inside the directory containing all the files (Use cd to change dir to it). I'm assuming all files are in a single directory.

Comment: That worked though the string doesn't contain an "E", ie "S0101" instead of "S01E01". How could I change the code to do this?

Comment: Do you still have the unrenamed files or are you stuck with the "half way renamed" ones?

Comment: I made a copy to test it so I still have the originals - I'll have to do this process in the future so I'd love to get the addition of the E with the code you gave above, if possible.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Is there a way to get it to look into folders contained in the specified directory and edit the contents - I have files filed by season...

Comment: Assuming that directories do not have dashes in their name, simply replace the * with \`find\`

Answer (score 1):

The following script will find all .mp4 with one string of 3 consecutive numbers. Example something.111.mp4 . It will convert it to something.S01E11.mp4 . It will also exclude any sample files.

```
find . ! -name "*sample*" -name '*.[0-9][0-9][0-9].*.mp4' -type f | while read filename; do mv -v "${filename}" "`echo $filename | sed -e 's/[0-9]/S0&E/;s/SS00E/S0/g'`";done;
```

Like the previous script it will only work if less than 10 seasons.

For those that are trying to personalize for their current directory tree, I would recommend learning the sed and find command. They are pretty powerful, are simple, and will allow you to substitute any string within a file name.

Comment: You probably want `*[0-9][0-9][0-9]*.mp4` (no periods - based on the OP's format). Also, by determining your `mv` target via `basename`, you're _moving files to `.`_ instead of renaming them in their present location (which could be any subdirectory in the current directory's subtree).

Answer (score 1):

The following solution:

- works with both 3-digit and 4-digit season+episode specifiers (e.g. `107` for season 1, episode 7, or `1002` for season 10, episode 2)
- demonstrates advanced `find` and `bash` techniques, such as:

  - the `-regex` primary to match filenames by regular expression (rather than wildcard pattern, as with `-name`)
  - `execdir` to execute a command in the same directory as each matching file (where `{}` contains the matching file *name*  only)
  - invoking an ad-hoc `bash` script that demonstrates regular-expression matching with `=~` and capture groups reported via the built-in `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}` variable; command substitution (`$(...)`) to left-pad a value with zeros; variable expansion to extract substrings (`${var:n[:m]}`).

```bsh
# The regular expression for matching filenames (without paths) of interest:
# Note that the regex is partitioned into 3 capture groups 
# (parenthesized subexpressions) that span the entire filename: 
#  - everything BEFORE the season+episode specifier
#  - the season+episode specifier,
#  - everything AFTER.
# The ^ and $ anchors are NOT included, because they're supplied below.
fnameRegex='(.+ - )([0-9]{3,4})( - .+)'

# Find all files of interest in the current directory's subtree (`.`)
# and rename them. Replace `.` with the directory of interest.
# As is, the command will simply ECHO the `mv` (rename) commands.
# To perform the actual renaming, remove the `echo`.
find -E . \
 -type f -regex ".+/${fnameRegex}\$" \
 -execdir bash -c \
   '[[ "{}" =~ ^'"$fnameRegex"'$ ]]; se=$(printf "%04s" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}");
   echo mv -v "{}" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}S${se:0:2}E${se:2}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `perl` `rename` implementation which easily can take care of proper padding and works for any number of seaons and episodes (<100, but can easily be adapted to your current format):

```
$ ls -1 *.avi
My Show - 0301 - Qux.avi
My Show - 101 - Foo.avi
My Show - 102 - Bar.avi
My Show - 1102 - Blah.avi
My Show - 201 - Quux.avi

$ rename -n 's/- (\d+)(\d{2,}) -/sprintf("- S%02dE%02d -", $1, $2)/e' *.avi
My Show - 0301 - Qux.avi renamed as My Show - S03E01 - Qux.avi
My Show - 101 - Foo.avi renamed as My Show - S01E01 - Foo.avi
My Show - 102 - Bar.avi renamed as My Show - S01E02 - Bar.avi
My Show - 1102 - Blah.avi renamed as My Show - S11E02 - Blah.avi
My Show - 201 - Quux.avi renamed as My Show - S02E01 - Quux.avi
```

I think [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh/) ships with the correct version, so it's just a matter of installing via

```
$ brew install rename
```

Comment: +1 for pointing us to a great utility; looks like you still have to combine it with `find` to process an entire directory _tree_, though, right?

Comment: @mklement0 Yes, unfortunately. But the biggest problem is that many distros ship with `util-linux`' `rename` OOTB instead so you always have to double check if the `rename` on your system is actually the "correct" one.

Comment: Ah, I now see what you meant by correct version. Yes, Homebrew does host the _Perl_ version (version `1.600` as of this writing). The Perl `s/.../<someExpr>/e` construct (treating the replacement string as a chunk of _code_ - is really neat. Don't know why someone voted this answer down.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks! I too think this is really neat although I never used `s///e` with `rename` before, it only occurred to me the other day how useful that combination is. I guess that `zsh` users can achieve the same via `zmv` but I'm not sure. As for the downvote, I have an educated guess as to who did and he got banned for serial-downvoting someone else before so I am not surprised. Thanks for confirming that homebrew's rename formula is indeed the correct one :-)