# bash shell: change multiple file names to add leading zeros

Tags: bash, shell

I have several files with this pattern: `prefix.1.*`, `prefix.2.*`, `prefix.3.*`, etc... and I want their name to be changed, respectively, to `prefix.01.*`, `prefix.02.*`, `prefix.03.*`, etc.  With that, they will be properly sorted by name as there are filenames with already two digits (e.g. `prefix.27.*`) in the set.

How can I do that using commands available in the bash shell?

---

Note: Just after this issue, I had to cope with a list of files like `prefix.1.*`, `prefix.2.*`, `prefix.17.*`, `prefix.157.*` (arbitrary, not sequentially numbered), with the aim to convert to `prefix.001.*`, `prefix.002.*`, `prefix.017.*`, `prefix.157.*`, with a generic way of inserting the right number of leading zeros. If you face this situation, I strongly recommend you to follow the general solution provided by [mklement0 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23940342/45375) (*More generic renaming solutions*) below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for file in prefix.[0-9].*
do
   mv "$file" "${file/prefix./prefix.0}"
done
```

Comment: Nice, but you probably meant `"${files[@]}"` instead of `files`; also,  there's no reason to use `extglob` (as an aside: you probably meant `shopt -s extglob` - just `shopt extglob` will merely _report the current state_ of the option); using `for file in prefix.[0-9].*` directly should suffice. Generally speaking (not strictly needed in this case), you should double-quote your variable [expansion] references; i.e.: `"$file"` and `"${file/prefix./prefix.0}"`. Finally - as long as you use the array- if the `*` in your glob expands to something with embedded whitespace, your solution will break.

Comment: Thanks for the update; I kept updating my comment, so you may not have seen the final version: the `in files` part still won't work; if you replace it with `in prefix.[0-9]*` (and ditch the `files` array), all problems go away - i.e., even filenames with embedded whitespace will be handled correctly.

Comment: @mklement0 The way the OP posed the question, I didn't think there would be any whitespaces in the file names. Valid point, though.

Comment: Point taken, but it makes _me_ happy. :); +1. Kidding aside, I feel SO benefits from _generic, robust_ answers - if the cost of improving one's answer in these respects is reasonably low - as in this case - I feel it's worth doing. (The alternative is to point out the limitations.)

Comment: @RSahu and @mklement0, thank you both for yours answers and, moreover, for your collaboration in this robust answer, that I am accepting. Only as a semi-off-topic comment: after this issue, I had to cope with a list of files like `prefix.1.*`, `prefix.2.*`, `prefix.17.*`, `prefix.157.*`, so I finally used python to convert to `prefix.001.*`, `prefix.002.*`, `prefix.017.*`, `prefix.157.*` with a generic way of inserting the right number of leading zeros.

Comment: @khyox: My pleasure; If you find yourself needing to perform such renaming tasks more frequently, I suggest you look at the Perl-based `rename` utility, which is very flexible. I've added another answer based on it that does what you describe in your comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23940342/45375

Comment: @mklement0: Many thanks indeed for your additional answer! Unfortunately, I have both the two issues you mention there: on the one hand, the server I am working with, uses the _Scientific Linux_ distro, which is using `rename` as part of the _util-linux-ng_ package. On the other hand, the files, as I tried to show in my comment, are not sequentially numbered.

Comment: @khyox: My pleasures; I always learn from answering. Sorry to hear that the `rename` utilities clash (is simply renaming the Perl-based one an option?). As for files not being sequentially numbered: I added another solution to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**More generic renaming solutions**, prompted by later comments by the OP:

Uses the **Perl-based `rename` utility**, which comes standard on *some* Linux distros (e.g., Ubuntu). *Caveat*: some distros have a *different* utility of the same name from the `util-linux` package.
On OS X, you can install via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) using `brew install rename`.

**Both solutions determine the required padding width *dynamically*.**

---

#### Simpler solution, in case files are *already numbered sequentially* and *only padding* must be performed *[does NOT meet the OP's requirements - see other solution below]*:

```
printf '%s\n' prefix.[0-9]*.* |                # enumerate files of interest
  sort -t. -n -k2,2 |                          # sort them by the embedded number
    rename -n -N '...01' -e 's/\.\d+\./.$N./'  # rename with appropriate padding
```

- `-n` performs a dry-run only, showing only what *would* happen; remove it to perform actual renaming
- `-N '...01'` specifies the format for the special counter variable `$N` in a way that *auto-determines appropriate zero-padding based on the number of input files*.
- `'s/\.\d+\./.$N./'` is a Perl expression that replaces the existing number component with the appropriately padded counter variable `$N`.

---

#### More sophisticated solution that *preserves existing numbers* and merely pads them.

In this case, the padding width is derived from the *largest existing number embedded in the filenames*:

```
# Determine the longest (largest) number contained in the matching filenames...
maxNum=$(printf '%s\n' prefix.[0-9]*.* | sort -nrt. -k2,2 | head -1 | cut -d. -f2)
# ... and derive the padding length from it.
padLength=${#maxNum}

# Perform renaming by zero-padding the *existing* numbers in the filenames.
rename -n -e 's/\.(\d+)\./sprintf(".%0'${padLength}'s.", $1)/e' prefix.[0-9]*.*
```

- `-n` performs a dry-run only, showing only what *would* happen; remove it to perform actual renaming
- Note the use of Perl's `e` flag in the `s/.../.../` command, which allows use of an arbitrary Perl expression in the replacement string; in this case, an `sprintf` expression is used to zero-pad the input number; credit for this approach belongs to @Adrian Frühwirth's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23359228/45375).

---

On a general note, matching filenames could be made more robust with `shopt -s extglob` and `prefix.+([0-9]).*`; similarly, `shopt -s nullglob` would make it easier to determine whether *any* files matched.

Comment: Impressive! Thank you very much again for your commitment to completeness!

Comment: Thanks, @khyox. I'm glad you find it useful.

Comment: I added a note to my question to point towards this answer  in the appropriate cases.

Answer (score 1):

Note a pure `bash` solution, but a little more concise(*):

```
printf '%s\0' prefix.[0-9].* | 
  xargs -0 -I % bash -c 'f="%"; mv "$f" "${f/\./.0}"'
```

This assumes that glob `prefix.[0-9].*` expands to at least 1 actual filename.
If it's possible that NO files match, execute `shopt -s nullglob` first (and, if required, restore that shell option's value later).

---

**Performance note**:

While this is more *concise* than [@R Sahu's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23818865/45375), it will *perform worse*, due to spawning an additional child shell (`bash -c`) for every input filename - so as to be able to assign the filename to a variable and use expansion on it.

---

(*) In terms of character count, [@R Sahu's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23818865/45375) is actually shorter, but the absence of a *loop* (and fewer lines) may result in this answer being *perceived* as shorter. At the end of the day, **this solution doesn't add much in itself - except perhaps as an advanced example of using `xargs`**:

- `printf '%s\0'` ensures that all matching filenames are passed through the pipeline with NUL chars. as separators.
- `xargs -0` then ensures that the filenames are recognized individually, even if they contain embedded whitespace.
- `-I %` ensures that *each* input filename results in its own invocation of the command that follows, with `%` instances replaced with the filename at hand.
- `bash -c` then invokes a child shell (a child process that happens to be another `bash` instance) and evaluates the specified string.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found was just entering this line in the bash shell:

```
for ITER in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do for FILE in prefix."$ITER".*; do mv "$FILE" $(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/prefix.'$ITER'/prefix.0'$ITER'/'); done; done
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way>>

```
#!/bin/bash
count=1
for i in $(ls prefix*)
do
Newname=prefix\.$(printf "%02d" $count)\.txt
mv $i $Newname
count=$(($count + 1))
done
```

Comment: Promising, but it's better to use pathname expansion directly ([don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)); to be safe, you should also double-quote your variable references (so that filenames with, e.g., embedded whitespace are handled correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Great answers so far. If the extension is same of all the files. Just use following. Here the extension is `.jpg`
you can change `prefix_` to your choice of prefix.
Also if you want more leading zeros just change %02 to %03 and so on.

```
rename -n -e 's/\d+/sprintf("prefix_%02d",$&)/e' -- *.jpg
```